# How to user upgraded version of openssl on el capitan

Tags: php, macos, openssl, homebrew

I'm trying to install Composer on OS X El Capitan with their [installation tutorial](https://getcomposer.org/download/), but I'm getting an error:

```
Composer successfully installed to: /Users/dmytrokomar/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
Some settings on your machine may cause stability issues with Composer.
If you encounter issues, try to change the following:

The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.
```

So I'm performed:

> brew update
>
> brew doctor
>
> brew upgrade openssl

After that `openssl version -a` shows: `OpenSSL 1.0.2h  3 May 2016`

but I'm still getting first the error ;(

Comment: rebooted after update?